# Creating a global delegate class inside AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

Apologies in advance if the Question titles is accurate. I have outlined below the basic flow of what I want to achieve.

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, SomeFrameworkDelegate, OtherFrameworkDelegate>


…other init stuff
```

**AppDelegate.m**

- Include the `SomeFrameworkDelegate` and `OtherFrameworkDelegate` methods.
- These methods mainly output messages such as connected/ disconnected from service.

**MainViewController**

- Do stuff with these delegate methods.
- Perform UI actions when connected/ disconnected. etc

**DetailsViewController**

- Use the same stuff as in the MainViewController.

**NOTES:**

- I assume I’d be setting global variables in the AppDelegate, then in the other UI code, I’d be creating an instance of the AppDelegate:

  `AppDelegate *appDelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
  appDelegate.isConnected = ...
  appDelegate.serviceName = ...`

*How would I detect when a message arrives to the delegate methods? NSNotificationCenter/ NSTimer?*

i.e. post a notification once a delegate method is fired or create a timer to poll the variables in appDelegate.

Comment: Do you mean that; you have some variables in your AppDelegate and you want other classes to be notified when they change value? If so then you probably should use KVC.... otherwise I don't fully understand your question.

Comment: Since you are changing the values in the delegate methods, you can post a notification in there. That way any View controllers that are interested, would all be notified about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to handle/manage a connection in your application delegate. The AppDelegate's purpose is to respond to application level events like applicationdidbecomeactive/applicationwillenterforeground. My recommendation is that you create a singleton to manage your connection. This is commonly referred to the sharedInstance pattern. This singleton should implement the managedObject's delegate functions. You have several options after they are implemented.

- Key-Value Observing or KVO (http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/)
- NSNotificationCenter (http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/)

In this case, I recommend using NSNotification since you're trying to figure out a connection status change. If you want to be notified of every change to your object's properties, then you should use KVO.

Answer (score 0):

You've answered your own question really. I would use `NSNotificationCenter` to post a notification in the delegate method when it is triggered. Then, in your view controller, observe that notification and respond.